# How to receive Redis publish message when Redis server crash

Tags: redis

I have an exercise about Redis Pubsub like the following:

In case the publisher publish a message but the subscriber has not received the server has crashed. How to subscriber receive that message when restart server?.

Please help me, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

In this case, **the message is gone forever**.

Redis only has limited support for `PUBSUB` scenario. Besides your case, if the connection between Redis and the client is lost, the client will also lose all published messages.

If you need more reliable `PUBSUB` tools, you should try other stuffs, e.g. `Kafka`, `RabbitMQ`.